# How do I use TryParse or Try catch to explain to the user what he's doing wrong?

Tags: c#

So I'm new to programming and can't seem to figure out how to solve this problem that I've got. When the user enters a letter instead of a number I want to explain to him what he did wrong. I've set up a try catch but I get an error that says "Use of unassigned local variable 'number' ".

Would really appreciate any help! 
/Alex

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // variables
        Random slumpat = new Random(); 
        int gameNumber = slumpat.Next(1, 20); 
        int number;

        bool play = true; 

        while (play)
        {
            Console.Write("\n\tGuess a number between 1 and 20: ");
        try {
            Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number);
            }
        catch 
            {
            console.WriteLine("This only works with numbers!");
            }

            if (number < gameNumber)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("\tThe number you entered " + number + " is too small, try again.");
            }

            else if (number > gameNumber)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\tThe number you entered " + number + " is too big, try again.");
            }

            else if (number == gameNumber)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\tYou guessed right!");
                play = false;
            }

        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Int32.TryParse *returns* a value for you to inspect and act upon, if its true the integer is within the number variable - it will not throw an exception if the conversion fails, rather it will return false.

Comment: Not quite - TryParse returns a boolean indicating whether or not the value was sucessfully parsed. The parsed term is available as an "out" parameter...

Comment: ...if you did want it to throw, just use the `Parse` method in place of `TryParse`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler has detected that, if your `try` block throws an exception before `TryParse` runs, the `number` variable will never have a value assigned to it, so it won't allow you to use it later on.

Even when you're sure the code inside the `try` block couldn't possibly fail, the compiler is not.

```
int number;

try
{
    Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number);
}
catch 
{
    Console.WriteLine("This only works with numbers!");
}

if (number < gameNumber)  // if "try" fails, number is undefined
```

You're part way there. The call to `TryParse` already returns `false` if the conversion failed, so use that return value to decide when to display an error message to your user.

```
int number;

if (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number))
{
    // parse failed ("number" is now 0), display message to user
    Console.WriteLine("This only works with numbers!");

    // start the next iteration of the loop, prompting the user again
    // (otherwise, the number comparison runs, telling the user their guess is too small)
    continue;
}

if (number < gameNumber)
```

Comment: This doesn't work if, say, something was done in the main loop *before* asking for a number.

Comment: The continue that @GrantWinney had in his example is extremely important!

If your declaration was `int number=0;` your program would run. However number would be set to 0 whenever the parse failed, and you would then process the guess as being 0. In short you are roughly saying "That input was invalid, now I will process it like it is valid"

The continue lets you stop processing of the invalid input.

Answer (score 4):

You already have some good answers; summarizing them:

- The "not assigned" error is because the compiler only considers `number` to be assigned *when control leaves the call to `TryParse` normally*. In your program control could leave `TryParse` normally, or (the compiler reasons) the `TryParse` or `ReadLine` could throw, and then `number` would never have been given a value by the time that the `catch` executes.
- The `try` is pointless in the first place because `TryParse` doesn't throw. That's why it is called `TryParse`. This is a bit confusing. `TryParse` is not "parse that needs a `try`. That's `Parse`. `TryParse` is `Parse` that (logically or actually) does the `try` for you.

So that said, you have another logical problem in your code. Suppose that it worked the way you expected; the method throws, you catch the exception, you print the message, and... then what?  You keep running the rest of the loop! You forgot to `continue` or `break` the loop, or use an `if` to make sure that the bottom of the loop does not run if the user enters bad input.

Frankly the better thing to do here would be to break up your program into smaller problems and make a method that solves each problem. I know this is a short program already, but good habits start early. Make a method that takes a prompt string and returns a number that was entered by the user. That's a basic logical part of your program, and so it can be put into a method and tested independently of the rest of the program.

A small point:  `"foo " + number + " bar"` is correct in C# but it would be more idiomatic to say

```
Console.WriteLine("foo {0} bar", number);
```

in any version of C#, or in C# 6:

```
Console.WriteLine($"foo {number} bar");
```

Comment: By convention (not sure whose?) every `Try...` method contains `try`/`catch` inside and is not supposed to `throw`.

Comment: @Sinatr: The second half of your sentence is true: a `Try` method should not throw. There is no requirement that a `Try` method contain a `try` block. `TryParse` does not have to be implemented as `result = 0; try { result = Parse(whatever); return true; } catch { return false; }`. It could be implemented by checking to see if the input contains any invalid characters, for instance, and returning `false`.

Comment: @Sinatr, most likely Parse() is implemented by calling TryParse and throwing the exception if TryParse returns false.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `Int32.TryParse` incorrectly. It tries to parse the value. If it succeeds, it sets `number` to the parsed value and returns `true`. Otherwise, it just returns `false`. In your instance, it works like this:

```
Console.Write("\n\tGuess a number between 1 and 20: ");
while (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number))
{
    Console.Write("This only works with numbers! Enter another one: ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TryParse doesn't result in an exception to catch - try this instead:

```
using System;

namespace GuessMyNumber
{
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // variables
        Random slumpat = new Random(); 
        int gameNumber = slumpat.Next(1, 20); 
        int number;

        bool play = true; 

        while (play)
        {
            Console.Write("\n\tGuess a number between 1 and 20: ");
            if (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number))
            {
            Console.WriteLine("This only works with numbers!");
            }
            else
            {

                if (number < gameNumber)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("\tThe number you entered " + number + " is too small, try again.");
                }

                else if (number > gameNumber)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\tThe number you entered " + number + " is too big, try again.");
                }

                else if (number == gameNumber)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\tYou guessed right!");
                    play = false;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: @LegionMammal978 If `TryParse` fails then `number` will be set to 0.